# Cannot assign JSON array or JSON object to a JSON using SwiftyJson in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have a JSON object:

```
var x: JSON = JSON([:])
x["1"].intValue = 1                      //Correct
x["2"].arrayValue = [JSON("2")]          //Error
x["3"].dictionaryValue = [3:JSON("3")]   //Error
```

I am able to assign an integer to x, but I am not able to assign any JSON array or any JSON dictionary. What am I doing wrong and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you originally wanted to assign an array of JSON objects:

```
// doesnt work
x["1"].arrayObject = [ JSON( ["1" : "2"] ), JSON( [ "3" : "4" ] )
```

Try this:

```
x["1"] = JSON( [ JSON( ["1" : "2"]), JSON( ["3" : "4"] ) ] )
```

Or:

```
x["1"] = [ JSON( ["1" : "2"]).object, JSON( ["3" : "4"] ).object ]
```

Should work at least for SwiftyJSON 2.3

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the SwiftyJSON README.md tells you to use

```
json.array = [1,2,3,4]
```

but actually take a look at SwiftyJSON.swift under MARK: - Array, extension JSON. array and arrayValue are get only, you should instead use

```
json.arrayObject = [1,2,3,4]
```

which works if the array elements are native types. If you would like to assign a [JSON] to a JSON, that is, an array of JSON objects to a new JSON object try this

```
// Patch SwiftyJSON to support constructing a JSON out of [JSON]
extension JSON {
    public init(_ jsonArray:[JSON]) {
        self.init(jsonArray.map { $0.object })
    }
}
```

and thus

```
json["subarray"] = JSON(someArrayOfJSON)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var x = JSON([:])

x["1"] = 1
x["2"] = [2]
x["3"] = ["3":4]

println(x)
```

Comment: Hi. The example that I gave is not the exact code I am working on. I want to put a JSON array in the JSON object and I am looking for a way to do that. The above is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rishi Just assign the array like `x["2"] = [2,3,4,5]`, isn't this working?

Comment: It works. But that is an array. I want to assign a JSON array.

Comment: @Rishi I'm kind of confused. What is exactly a JSON array?

Comment: @Rishi After `x["2"] = [2,3,4,5]`, we can print `x` and see the array printed in the json. That doesn't mean it's now a JSON array?

Comment: A JSON array is an array of JSON objects. Check SwiftyJSON.

Comment: @Rishi I'm using SwiftyJSON. A JSON object can be directly initialized using `=`. `let y:JSON = [1,2,3]` and `let z = [1,2,3]` makes `y` a JSON array which contains three JSON int objects, and `z` a Swift Array. Isn't this correct?

Comment: Suppose I have an array like this `let z = [JSON(2), JSON("3"), JSON(1)]`, this is a JSON array.

Comment: @Rishi Now I got what you meant. But what's the point of make an JSON array like this exactly?